# Preventing iOS deep link modal

Tags: javascript, html, mobile-safari

I need a redirect to a native iOS application, if the application is not installed, then a redirect to the App Store.

I already tried different methods like window.location.replace() and iframe with app url in src.

`window.location.replace("MyIOSAPP://")` is causing native safari modal with error, then nothing happends, I tried to catch that with `trycatch` construction, it doesn't get caught in the `catch` callback.

I also tried `<iframe/>`

```
const iframe = document.createElement("iframe");

iframe.style.border = "none";
iframe.style.width = "1px";
iframe.style.height = "1px";

iframe.onload = function () {
    document.location = "MyIOSAPP://";
};

iframe.src = "MyIOSAPP://"; //iOS app schema url

document.body.appendChild(iframe);

setTimeout(function () {
    window.location.href = "appstore url"; //fallback url
}, 300);
```

Link to `MyIOSAPP://` is ignored, the setTimeout callback fires and I am being redirected to App Store without trying to open the native iOS app.

Please, help me solve this problem